# Can't send requests from py script to flask on ECS but from postman it works

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, postman, amazon-ecs

I have **Flask** on top of **ECS**, trying to send **req** (from local script) with Python `requests` \ `http.client` but it does not get to the **ECS** (don't see it in logs), but when trying with `Postman` (web and locally) it succeeds.

Any ideas why?

## Flask:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/infr", methods=["POST"])
def transformation():
 doing something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

## Python script 1

```
def exec_task(task, out):
        import http.client
        import json

        url = "<ecs-public-ip>"
        port = 8080
        endpoint = "/infr"

        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(url, port)
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Connection": "keep-alive"}

        data = {
            "task": {
                "bucket": task.bucket,
                "prefix": task.prefix,
                "metadata": task.metadata
            }
        }

        payload = json.dumps(data)

        conn.request("POST", endpoint, body=payload, headers=headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()

        if response.status == 200:
            print("\nRequest successful")
            response_data = json.loads(response.read().decode())
            out.put(ProcessedTask(bucket=task.bucket, prefix=task.prefix, metadata=response_data))
        else:
            print("\nRequest failed")

        conn.close()
```

## Python script 2

```
def exec_task(task, out):
        import requests

        url = "http://<ecs-public-ip>:8080/infr"
        data = {"task": {
            "bucket": task.bucket,
            "prefix": task.prefix,
            "metadata": task.metadata
        }}
        
        print("sending: " + str(data))
        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Connection": "keep-alive"}
        response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("\nRequest successful")
            response_data = response.json()
            out.put({ProcessedTask(bucket=task.bucket, prefix=task.prefix, metadata=response_data)})
        else:
            print("\nRequest failed")
```

## Postman

[image]

- Note: Port 8080 is used. Removed by mistake

Comment: Start by testing with a simplified script that just sends a basic request using `requests`. Catch any errors and update the post

Comment: Your postman configuration appears to be hitting the default `http` port, which is port `80`, not `8080`, unless you removed the port when you put in `<ecs-public-ip>`. Also, what is the response that the python script receives? Instead of just printing "request failed" you should actually print the response values, like the response code that was received.

Comment: @Obaskly i did so, no respose is sent back, the script just ends, no errors, nothing.
thanks!

Comment: @MarkB yes i removed the port by mistake, it is 8080.
as i said above, no respose is sent, the "request failed" isnt firing, nothing at all
thanks!

Comment: There's no way that script can just exit without either an exception, or executing the print statement in either the `if` or the `else` block. Is this part of a larger script that is throwing away an exception or something? Or is the code in the question not really representative of the code you are actually running?

Comment: @MarkB found the problem. for some reason an exception was raised and stdout nor vscode debug did not catch it so it just ended the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem. for some reason an exception was raised and stdout nor vscode debug did not catch it so it just ended the program.

Comment: @Rich it is the complete answer... once i could read stdout i saw the problem and fixed it.
The post talks about the unability to find the problem, not the problem itself